# Why a method is modifying a List<string> variable in my Load Page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to create two List with methods, the first method create a new list, and the second modify the first one but return a new one. For example, the first list has 200 items, and after add and delete some items in the second method, the returned one has 120 items.
But the second method is actually modifying the first list (now both list has 120 items).
What am I doing wrong?.
PD. I'm learning

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> firstList = OEEClass.GetCompleteListDocument(DateTime.Today, "BZX"); // Let say it has 200 items
    List<string> modifiedList = OEEClass.ModifyList(firstList); // The returned list has less items
}

public class OEEClass
{
    public static List<string> GetCompleteListDocument(DateTime Fecha, string noMaquina)
    {            
        var rawDoc = new HtmlDocument();
        var tempList = new List<string>();

        string url = @"C:/www/WPCS-Feedback/" + Fecha.Year + "/" + Fecha.Month + "/" + Fecha.Day.ToString("d2") + "/" + "Production state data.htm";

        if (File.Exists(url) == true)
        {
            rawDoc.Load(url);

            string cleanString = rawDoc.DocumentNode.InnerText.Trim().Replace(" ", "");
            cleanString = Regex.Replace(cleanString, @"^\s+$[\r\n]*", string.Empty, RegexOptions.Multiline);

            tempList = Regex.Split(cleanString, "\r\n|\r|\n").ToList();
            tempList.RemoveRange(0, 5);

            for (int j = 0; j < tempList.Count; j++)
            {
                if (tempList[j].StartsWith("ProductionTerminated") || tempList[j].StartsWith("ProductionInterrumpted"))
                {
                    tempList.Insert(j + 4, "PressSingleCycleActivated=0");
                }

            }

        }

        return tempList;
    }

    public static List<string> ModifyList(List<string> completeListDocument)
    {        
        for (int i = 0; i < completeListDocument.Count; i++)
        {
            if (completeListDocument[i].StartsWith("MachineSetup"))
            {
                completeListDocument.RemoveRange(i, 6);
                i--;
            }

        }
        return completeListDocument;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way anyone here can tell you what is wrong with your `ModifyList` method if you're not going to post what it's actually doing. All way can do is guess that somehow you're actually modifying the `completeListDocument` instance. Since you say you're learning, I hope you know the difference between value types and reference types? If not then this is an excellent time to learn about the differences. Short story, what you passed to your `ModifyList` method isn't a copy of the list, it's a reference to the one list you have in memory.

Comment: Obviously that is not your real code, and you have not shown the actual problem

Comment: I would suggest calling `tempList = completeListDocument.ToList()` before doing anything with it (if you are)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen This is maybe my problem, I need to read about value types and references types. I will add the real code, just in case. Thank you.

Comment: Please **do not** blindly add "real code" - we need [MCVE] which is most likely different from what you have in your program, we are looking for code that demonstrates the problem but without any extra stuff.

Comment: The crucial code needed to explain what's going on is not in your question. Posting `// Modify the last list and return A NEW ONE` takes away our ability to give you a concrete answer.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov thank you for your advice. The code is really simple, actually.

Comment: This is what is modifying your list: `completeListDocument.RemoveRange(i, 6);`. You're not working with a copy of your original list, you only have one list object in memory and you're working directly on that list, modifying it. You can do what @TheGeneral suggested earlier, make a copy of it first. Simplest change would be to add this line first thing inside `ModifyList`: `completeListDocument = completeListDocument.ToList();`. I would suggest you actually declare a new variable inside the method, like: `var result = completeListDocument.ToList();` and then modify `result` instead though.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I wear to anyone that I tried something like `var newList = completeListDocument;` but maybe the `.ToList()` do the trick. Thank you.

Comment: `var x = y;` when dealing with reference types only copies the reference. Think of reference types as post it notes with addresses to houses. The fact that I give you a post it note with the address of a specific house on it doesn't mean there are now two houses, there's still only one house. If you go there and rearrange the furniture, everyone with a post it note with the same address on it can go to the same house and observe your changes. `.ToList()` on the list makes a new list, a second house if you will. Again, I urge you to go read about the differences, it will help you going forward.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Got it, I really thank you for your patience.  I will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing you can do is make a copy of your list before modifying it:

```
public static List<string> ModifyList(List<string> completeListDocument)
{
    var results = new List<string>(completeListDocument);
    for (int i = 0; i < results.Count; i++)
    {
        if (results[i].StartsWith("MachineSetup"))
        {
            results.RemoveRange(i, 6);
            i--;
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

Comment: I don't know if `var result = completeListDocument.ToList();` do the same thing for this works for me. Thank you.

Comment: @RobertoLopez - Yes, it's effectively the same thing, other than it uses the LINQ library - but it's most likely that you're using that anyway.